# Installing nodejs and nodered on Windows IoT Core

Tags: windows-iot, node.js, nodered

I'm trying to find out if it is posible to install nodejs and nodered on Windows IoT Core running on Raspberry Pi 3 where an UWP will be also running.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check [it (Windows Core IoT – NodeJS on a Raspberry PI3)](https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2018/01/15/windows-core-iot-nodejs-on-a-raspberry-pi3/) out? By this procedure, you can install node-red with `npm`.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't clear to me if I could install node red. Thanks!!

Comment: What is exactly not clear to you? Add some keynotes to the question if you have some problem with a procedure. Also, tag my username to the comments. Thanks.